# Integral Representation of Hermitian Conjugation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, complex-numbers, quantum-mechanics

My Quantum Physics textbook asserts that,
$$⟨u│u⟩=\int_{-∞}^{∞}\left|u\right|^{2}dx$$
Where the term,
$$⟨u│u⟩$$
denotes the product of u and its Hermitian conjugate.

What I am confused about is where did this "representation" come from? And how can it be derived mathematically? I don't see how this integral "representation" makes any mathematical sense.

Comment: Can you please specify what "data types" we're talking about here?  Presumably, $u$ is meant to be a function over $\Bbb R$.  However, in order for "the product of u and its Hermitian conjugate" to make sense, $u$ must presumably be a vector (or perhaps a sequence of coefficients).

Comment: Yes, "u" is a vector. The Textbook also states that "u", is a vector with an infinite amount of entries corresponding to a value out-putted by the "u" within the integral, given a real input.

Comment: If you tell me that "$u$ is a vector with an infinite amount of entries, each "entry" corresponds to a value out-putted by the $u$... given a real input", then the only interpretation I can reasonably make is that $u$ is a function $u$ is a function defined over $\Bbb R$.  If that is the case, then there is no way to take "the product of $u$ and its Hermtian conjugate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In quantum mechanics, the expression $\langle u | v \rangle$ is used to denote the [inner-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) of two vectors $u$ and $v$ (or, as a physicist might insist, $|u\rangle$ and $|v\rangle$).  What exactly this inner product is depends on the context.

When $u,v$ are vectors $u = (u_1,\dots,u_n)$ and $v = (v_1,\dots v_n)$ over $\Bbb C$, their inner-product is defined by
$$
\langle u|v\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n u_k^* v_k.
$$
When $u,v$ are functions $u,v: \Bbb R \to \Bbb C$, their inner-product is defined by
$$
\langle u|v \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u^*(x) v(x)\,dx.
$$
So, what exactly $\langle u|v \rangle$ means depends on how it is defined for the given context. In all cases though, this function has the properties that define an inner-product.

Comment: @daw actually the QM convention is reversed, but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

$⟨u│u⟩=\int_{-∞}^{∞}u(x) \overline{u(x)}dx$, hence $⟨u│u⟩=\int_{-∞}^{∞}\left|u(x)\right|^{2}dx$, since for a complex number $z$ we have $z \overline{z}=|z|^2.$

Comment: Yes, but were does,$$⟨u│u⟩=\int_{-∞}^{∞}u^{*}u\ dx$$ come from?

Comment: $u^*= \overline{u}.$

Comment: Yes, the asterix denotes the complex conjugate of "u".